# What is the difference between a short and ushort in C#?

Tags: c#, cpu-word, ushort

What is the difference between a <strike>word</strike> `short` and `ushort` in C#? They are both 16 bits!

Answer (score 25):

C# does not have a `word` type.  If you mean `short` or `Int16`, the difference is that `ushort` is unsigned.

`short` can be any value from `-32768` to `32767`, whereas `ushort` can be from `0` to `65535`.  They have the same total range and use the same number of bits but are interpreted in different ways, and have different maximums/minimums.

Clarification: A **word** is a general computer science term that is typically used to refer to the largest single group of bits that can be handled by the CPU in a single operation.  So if your CPU (and operating system) are 32-bit, then a word is an `Int32` or `UInt32` (C#: `int`/`uint`).  If you're on a 64-bit CPU/OS, a word is actually an `Int64/UInt64` (C#: `long`/`ulong`).  The term "word" usually refers only to the bit size of a variable as opposed to how it is actually interpreted in a program.

Comment: Ah thanks, I guess the lesson I was reading was just talking about it conceptually and I understood that there actually is a word type!

Comment: In addition, a language can have more than one name for a type. For instance, in C, an `int`, a `long`, and an `int32_t` are the same in some implementations.

Comment: @Adam: I added in a clarification which I think might help.  "Word" refers to a fixed-size group of bits; however, there may be many different ways that this word can be interpreted, each of which forms a type in a language (such as `int` or `uint`).

Comment: @Zarel: Yes, exactly.  IIRC, C++ and C typically typedef `WORD` as `unsigned int`, so in that case it is equivalent to the C# `uint`.  However, there are no such typedefs in C#, you have to explicitly specify `[u]short/int/long` and these are all aliases for the CLR structs `[U]Int16/Int32/Int64`.

Comment: No, WORD is 16 bits.  The first version of Windows ran on 16-bit CPUs.

Comment: @nobugz: You're right, `WORD` is `unsigned short` in windef.h, that was a mistake in my comment above.  It can still vary significantly by platform, though, and does not exist in C#, so I think that the concept of a machine word is the most important thing here; if someone decides to start programming in Windows C++ then they will quickly pick up the subtle differences, such as the `WORD` type being fixed to 16-bits for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

A **(machine) word** is the native size of the processor registers. It's generally what C has used as size for the `int` data type. In C# the data types has a fixed size and does not depend on the processor architecture.

In Intel assembly language the `WORD` data type has come to mean 16 bits, a `DWORD` (double word) is 32 bits and a `QWORD` (quad word) is 64 bits. The `WORD` type is also used in the Windows API with the same meaning.

So, the `WORD` data type corresponds to the C# type `ushort`.